# Where is the best place to get my beloved Rollei serviced?

Tags: film, repair, service-recommendation, old-cameras

My father gave me a old MF Rollei a few years ago. I've taken it everywhere I travel and gotten some great shots out of it. I know film is much more expensive and quickly going out of "style" as the digital revolution pushes on. (I'm not a Luddite as i shoot more on my DC than on film)

On my last trip to London the shutter locked up. I called around London to see if I could have it repaired and ended up not having it repaired in the UK but waited until I brought it back home.

One of the camera repair shops i spoke with in London told me that finding someone to fix your Rollei is like finding a good car mechanic. If you find a good one stick with them as they will repair things the RIGHT way and not the cheap/fast way. I was told by my local repair guy that the camera had previously been fixed and it was not done correctly. It's not that I don't trust the local camera guy. I just think this camera is so far out of his normal repairs that it should be sent to a real expert.

Has anyone ever sent their cameras out for repair and had *excellent* service? If so, where is the best place to get my beloved Rollei serviced?

Comment: Why not asking directly to Rollei? There is a contact for old camera on thier site 

http://www.rcp-technik.com/typo3/index.php?id=service&L=1

Comment: you can send an email to http://www.keh.com/ they have a repair center. I did't try to repair something with them but they sell old cameras and they may know how to deal with your Rollei. I purchased many things from Keh and they are really good.

Answer (score 3):

I had a Leica M3 done last year, the shutter speeds were off, it had shutter-bounce issues and was dry as a bone. It came back smooth as butter and good for another ten years methinks. I used Will van Manen, http://www.kamera-service.info , they are a small Dutch outfit and they do handle Rolleis. The price for the Leica CLA was quite reasonable, two hundred something Euros, and turnaround was quick.